# How to Set Left and Right Margins to Absolute 0

Tags: ms-word

I have to create a document with absolute 0 margins in left and right sides. The problem is word is forcing to left at lest `0.41cm` for margins. can you please let me know how I can make them zero?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in word 2010, definitely try hitting ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't clicking Ignore do what you want?